# Python requests stream reads more data than chunk size

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using python requests library to stream the data from a  streaming API.

```py
response = requests.get('http://server/stream-forever', stream=True)
for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
    print len(chunk) # prints 1905, 1850, 1909
```

I have specified the chunk size as 1024. Printing the length of the chunk read gives the chunk size greater than 1024 like 1905, 1850, 1909 and so on.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.iter_content - `The chunk size is the number of bytes it should read into memory. This is not necessarily the length of each item returned as decoding can take place.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`requests.Response.iter_content` docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.iter_content)

> (...)The chunk size is the number of bytes it should read into memory. This
> is not necessarily the length of each item returned as decoding can
> take place.(...)